# Array of random size

Tags: python, arrays, list, opencv

I'm trying to calculate the bending radius of a product under cyclic bending using image processing with OpenCV and Python.
The image processing part is defined (the code is at [Red dot coordinates detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61769416/red-dot-coordinates-detection) )

The code returns center coordinates of contours of specific size. I'm now trying to populate a 2D array of these coordinates so that I can use coordinates of two adjacent points to calculate the bending radius.

The problem is that the array population should be inside the for loop and that when I allocate the array beforehand, I don't know the size.

EDIT: bellow is the code from the link above with the FOR loop for filtering out the contours by area and displaying the center coordinates.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import imutils

#load image
img = cv2.imread('dot4_red.jpg')

#apply median blur, 15 means it's smoothing image 15x15 pixels

blur = cv2.medianBlur(img,15)

#convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#color definition
red_lower = np.array([0,0,240])
red_upper = np.array([10,10,255])

#red color mask (sort of thresholding, actually segmentation)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, red_lower, red_upper)

#copy image for, .findContours distorts the source image
mask_copy = mask.copy()

#find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask_copy,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#extract contours from the list??
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

#count number of conoturs of specific size
s1 = 500
s2 = 10000
array = [] #create empty array of no size

for cnt in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    moment = cv2.moments(cnt)
    if s1<area<s2:
        print area
        c_x = int(moment["m10"]/moment["m00"])
        c_y = int(moment["m01"]/moment["m00"])
        print (c_x, c_y)

        array.append(c_x, c_y)
```

Comment: We need to know what tools you are using. Some more detailed information would help us help you

Comment: What language are you using? If it's Python as in the linked question, [investigate `append()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252703/1270789).

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to add the info on the language. I edited the original post with the code I have so far. I'm trying to add the array in the for loop used for filtering contours by area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `for`-loop you could use a `while`-loop with arbitrary termination criteria that you could calculate during the execution of your loop. And you could dynamically append to your array using `np.append()`, although it is not exactly efficient. I suggest you estimate the size of your array beforehand and only append if necessary.

Comment: but a while loop stops when it encounters a false result. I also noticed that the np.append() only "adds" one argument while I need to fill two coordinates at each step

Comment: Yes, but you could also implement it using `while(True):` and then `break` dynamically. You are completely free to append whatever objects you like. If you need one or two coordinates does not matter at all.

Comment: I checked the concept of while True, but I can't wrap my head around on how to implement that into my results of findContours which are in the form of a list (an array of point coordinates for every contour). I need to loop through these arrays, calculate the area and check if that area is within limits. I think I need to declare some variable (like i) to use it to loop through all the array. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understand your requirements, but would it be possible to do something like this: `i = 0; while(True): ... do processing on index i...; i += 1; if(doneProcessing): break`?

Comment: I found a solution, please see the answered question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to figure out how to extract the center coordinates. The code is bellow. The problem is that I did not understand how to define what I wanted in Python.

The solution is simple, I created two empty lists before the FOR loop and when the IF sentence filters out the contour of specific area, the x and y coordinates get written in separate lists. Then I can call specific coordinates for further calculation.

Thanks for all the pointers and ideas.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import scipy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import imutils

#load image
img = cv2.imread('dot4_red.jpg')

#apply median blur, 15 means it's smoothing image 15x15 pixels
blur = cv2.medianBlur(img,15)

#convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#color definition
red_lower = np.array([160,210,230])
red_upper = np.array([180,255,255])

#red color mask (sort of thresholding, actually segmentation)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, red_lower, red_upper)

#copy image for, .findContours distorts the source image
mask_copy = mask.copy()

#find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask_copy,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#extract contours from the list??
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

#contour size filter
s1 = 500
s2 = 10000

#calculate center coord and display data
x = []
y = []

for cnt in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    moment = cv2.moments(cnt)
    if s1<area<s2:
        print area
        c_x = int(moment["m10"]/moment["m00"])
        c_y = int(moment["m01"]/moment["m00"])
        x.append(c_x)
        y.append(c_y)
        print (c_x, c_y)

print x
print y
```